# Not seeing same value of integer upon returning to main class

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference, definition

I am working off some skeleton code for a hash table implementation. In the main class, there is a portion which checks for the key in the table. It allows for duplicates so the it is expecting to return an array of a specified size, and if the entries exceed that size then it is called again with a larger array. My issue is with the "num_results" pointer which is declared just before.

```
  int num_values = 1;

  valType* values = malloc(1 * sizeof(valType));

  int* num_results = NULL;

  get(ht, key, values, num_values, num_results);
  printf("num_results: %d\n", (*num_results));
  if ((*num_results) > num_values) {
    values = realloc(values, (*num_results) * sizeof(valType));
    get(ht, 0, values, num_values, num_results);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < (*num_results); i++) {
    printf("value of %d is %d \n", i, values[i]);
  }
  free(values);
```

It is declared to null (presumably because if there are no results then the memory isn't wasted?)

```
int get(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType *values, int num_values, int* num_results) {
  int slot = key % sizeof(ht);

  struct node *entry = ht->entries[slot];

  if(entry == NULL){
    printf("There are no matching hashed keys");
    return -1;
  }

  // Allocate the num_results, as just a NULL pointer was passed  
  if((num_results = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL){
    return -1;
  }
  // Start it at 0 so that it cxan be incremented as we check
  (*num_results) = 0;


  printf("num_results: %d\n", (*num_results));

  int temp = num_values;
  while(entry != NULL){
    if(entry->key == key){
      ++(*num_results);
      if(temp != 0){
        values[num_values-temp] = entry->value;
        --temp;
      }
    }
    entry = entry->next;
  }
  printf("num_results: %d\n", (*num_results));

  return 0;
}
```

This is the get function, and as you can see I allocate the memory needed, set it to 0, and it increments as expected. The output looks like:

```
num_results: 0
num_results: 2
num_results: 73896
```

This confuses me, as clearly the 2 result is from the last line of the method, and the last printout comes immediately after returning to the main... What is happening here? Why is the value changing?

Comment: What do you mean by "main class"? C doesn't have classes. Your program has a `main` function, but you haven't shown it to us. Please read this: [mre].

Comment: `int slot = key % sizeof(ht);` is a mistake

Comment: Thank you for the check there, I updated it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the pointer `num_results` by reference. Otherwise the function deals with a copy of the pointer.

For example

```
int get(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType *values, int num_values, int ** num_results) {
  // ...
  if(( *num_results = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL){
    return -1;
  }
  //…
```

A function call will look like

```
  get(ht, key, values, num_values, &num_results);
```

Actually I do not see a great sense to declare the variable `num_results` as a pointer and allocate dynamically a memory for it in the function.  I would declare it at least as having the type `unsigned int`.

For example

```
unsigned int num_results = 0;
```

and then the function get could look like

```
int get(hashtable* ht, keyType key, valType *values, int num_values, unsigned int *num_results) {
    //…
    *num_results = 0;
    //…
```

and called like

```
  get(ht, key, values, num_values, &num_results);
```

Pay attention to that instead of

```
int slot = key % sizeof(ht);
```

it seems you mean

```
int slot = key % sizeof( *ht);
```

Comment: This definitely works, and I will probably go forward using this implementation (also thank you for the slot hashtable pointer check). But to implement I am changing the code given to me, any idea why it is not working the way it is currently being done?

Comment: @Adam7397 I already wrote that the function deals with a copy of the original pointer. So changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

Comment: Right that makes sense, I just meant that the variable declarations, function declarations and function calls were all provided ahead of time and I need to modify them to use `&` on the function call and also remove the int null pointer. This does work, I just still am wondering why in my original code the int is changing

Comment: @Adam7397 Your original code has undefined behavior.